# Execute 2 loops for inserting values in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, plsql

I am using a procedure to get data from a table called **Datastream** which has 1000 rows and I have to read 100 records in a cursor once. And for each record match the primary key with foreign key in table **Masterdata** and move all the matching records in in multiple tables. Then the function should get the next 100 records from the table and do the same.
*P.S: I need to use 2 loops as a condition.*

I'm stuck with this error :

`ORA-01722: invalid number`

**EDIT 1:** Solved the above error, table datatype for 'product_id' was different then what it was supposed to be.

**New Error:** Everything seems fine, the procedure runs, but my tables aren't populated by the insert query. The output line prints SupID and PName.

I'm using the below code:

```
create or replace procedure newting is
s integer := 1;
e integer := s+99;
total_S integer := 1; 

    cursor endCount is 
    select datastream_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY datastream_id )
    from datastream
    where datastream_id <= (select (count(*)/100) from datastream);

    cursor transC is 
    SELECT datastream_id, product_id, customer_id, customer_name, outlet_id, outlet_name, quantity_sold, d_date
    from datastream
    where datastream_id between s and e
    order by datastream_id;

TYPE val1 IS TABLE OF datastream.datastream_id%type;
v1 val1;
TYPE val2 IS TABLE OF datastream.product_id%type;
v2 val2;
TYPE val3 IS TABLE OF datastream.customer_id%type;
v3 val3;
TYPE val8 IS TABLE OF datastream.d_date%type;
v8 val8;


PName masterdata.product_name%TYPE;
SupID masterdata.supplier_id%TYPE;
SName masterdata.supplier_name%TYPE;
PPrice masterdata.sale_price%TYPE;

begin
    
    open endCount;
    open transC;
    fetch transC bulk collect into v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7,v8;
    close endCount;
    close transC;
    
    for x in endCount
    loop
        for y in v1.first .. v1.last
        loop
            
            
        select product_name, supplier_id, supplier_name, sale_price into PName, SupID, SName, PPrice
        from masterdata m
        where m.product_id=v2(y);   
        Dbms_output.put_line(SupID);  
            
        insert into product (product_id, product_name) select v2(y), PName from dual --error in this line
        where not exists (select * from product where product_id=v2(y));    
        
        insert into customer (customer_id, customer_name) select v3(y), v4(y) from dual
        where not exists (select * from customer
                where customer_id=v3(y));
        
        insert into d_time (d_date, d_year, d_month, d_day) 
        select v8(y), to_char(v8(y),'YY'), to_char(v8(y),'MM'), to_char(v8(y),'DD') 
        from dual
        where not exists (select * from d_time
                where d_date=v8(y));
        
        total_S := v7(y) * PPrice;
        
        insert into sales_fact (transaction_id, product_id, supplier_id, outlet_id, customer_id, d_date, quantity, price, total_sales)
        select v1(y), v2(y), SupID, v5(y), v3(y), v8(y), v7(y), PPrice, total_S
        from dual
        where not exists (select * from sales_fact
                where transaction_id = v1(y));    
            
        end loop;
        s:=s+99;
        e:=e+99;
    end loop;
end;
```

Any leads on this would be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to convert a character string into a number you could get An ORA-01722 error, basically the message says string cannot be converted into a number. Check all your DML(INSERT) specially the ones for dates. my advice is comment all (INSERT) but one, try to run it and if there is not issue, so proceed with the second one and keep going till you manage to find the problematic one and fix it(divide and conquer). Something else(just an observation), I believe the 'COMMIT' is out of this proc scope right?

Hope this could help.